# Is it true that subset D is dense in space X iff every nonempty open set in X contains one point of D

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have a proposition that I am not sure if it is right:

Let D be a subset of space X. D is dense in X if and only if every nonempty open set U of X contains at least one point of D.

When X is a metric space, then I could verify that this is true in both directions.

When X is a topological space, I could prove the ==> direction; however the <== direction is so difficult that I doubt the proposition is right. However, I cannot yet find a counter example.

This proposition is the generalization of a property of real numbers R:

Q is dense in R so every open interval of R contains a point of Q.

Thank you.

Comment: what is your definition of density?

Comment: D is dense in X if closure of D is X, or equivalently, every point in X is the limit of a sequence in D. You think the proposition is exactly the definition of the density? I am taking "introduction to topology".

Comment: @Thang: It's worth noting, as Henno Brandsma mentions in the comments below, that sequential density (your second definition) is *not* equivalent in general to density (your first definition). Those definitions coincide for what are known as "sequential spaces," a class of topological spaces that includes metric spaces.

Comment: Many texts take the definition from the proposition as the definition of density, which is readily equivalent to the first one you gave.

Answer (score 6):

As to your definition: $D$ is dense when the closure of $D$ (a.k.a. $\overline{D}$) in $X$, equals $X$. (this does *not* mean in general that every point of $X$ is a limit of a convergent sequence from $D$; it does in metric spaces, but not in general topological spaces). So as the definition I will use $\overline{D} = X$.

Of course, now the solution will depend on the definition of the closure of a set $A$. Let's use the definition, or characterization, that $x \in \overline{A}$ iff for every open set $O$ of $X$ that contains $x$, $O$ intersects $A$.

Now the statement about the density of $D$ is pretty clear: if $D$ is dense and $O \neq \emptyset$ is open, then pick $p \in O$, then $p \in \overline{D}$, as $\overline{D} = X$, and so every open neighbourhood of $p$ intersects $D$; in particular $O$ intersects $D$, i.e. $O$ contains a point of $D$.

On the other hand, if every non-empty open set $O$ of $X$ contains a point of $D$, let $x \in X$. Let $O$ be any open set that contains $x$. Then $O$ is non-empty (because of $x$) and so contains a point of $D$, i.e. $O \cap D \neq \emptyset$. But this just says that $x \in \overline{D}$ by the definition above. As $x \in X$ was arbitrary, $X \subset \overline{D}$. As $\overline{D} \subset X$ by definition, we have equality.

Note that nothing at all of a metric is used. This is just a general fact for topological spaces.

Comment: Could you give me an example of a topological space X and a dense subset D of X such that there is a point x in X (and not in D) that is not the limit of any sequence in D.

Comment: A classical one: $D = \mathbb{N}$, $X = \beta\mathbb{N}$, the Cech-Stone compactification of $\mathbb{N}$. No point of $\beta\mathbb{N} \setminus \mathbb{N}$ is a limit of a sequence from $\mathbb{N}$, even though the latter dense set is dense in $\beta\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Proving by contrapositive would probably be easier. If $D$ is *not* dense, then its closure is not all of $X$. What can you then say about the complement of its closure? On the other hand, if there is a non-empty open set disjoint from $D,$ then the complement of this open set is closed and contains $D,$ but isn't all of $X,$ so what can we say about the closure of $D$?

Answer (score 2):

> $D$ is dense in $X$ if closure of $D$ is $X$, or equivalently, every point in $X$ is the limit of a sequence in $D$.

- Suppose $D$ is dense. Let $x\in X$, let $r>0$, $x_n\to x$ a $D$ valued sequence. As $$
  d(x_n,x) \to 0
  $$there is a $N$ such as $$
  n\ge N \Rightarrow d(x_n,x)< r
  $$
  In particular, $x_N\in B(x,r)\cap D$.
- Suppose that every open ball of $X$ contains an element of $D$.
  Let $x\in X$, let $x_n \in D\cap B(x,2^{-n})$. This is a $D$ valued sequence, and 
  $$ d(x_n,x) < 2^{-n}$$ so $x_n\to x$.

Now in a general topologic context:

- Suppose $D$ is dense. Let $x\in X$ and $x_n\to x$ a $D$ valued sequence. 
  Let $V$ an open set such as $x\in V$.
  As $x_n\to x$  there is a $N$ such as $$
  n\ge N \Rightarrow x_n\in V
  $$
  In particular, $x_N\in V\cap D$.
- There is no hope of a better result. Take for example the discret topology. $O = X - D$ is (as every subset) an open set, containing $x$ when $x\notin D$, such as $O\cap D = \emptyset$.

Comment: Thank you. However, this is the proof for metric space. I am asking if the proposition is still true when X is a general topological space. Then, there is no metric. There a lot of things that are true in a metric space, but it is very difficult to generalize it in a topological space. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: I edited for the general case (you were right).

Comment: Please do not use sequences for general spaces. They don't suffice for density in general spaces!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "no hope of a better result." The (non-sequential) definitions are equivalent even in general topological spaces. This includes discrete spaces, each of which has precisely one dense subset (itself).

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: I don't understand "[sequences] don't suffice for density in general spaces". I think using sequences in general topological space is fine. The definition of limit of a sequence in a topological space is: sequence x_n approaches L if for every open set containing L, there exists a number N such that the open set contains all x_n for n > N.

Comment: @Thang I know. But in a general space, $D$ being dense does *not* imply that for every $x$ in $X$ there is a sequence from $D$ converging to it. On the other hand, *if* there is such a sequence for every point, $D$ is dense, but the notion of sequentially dense is not equivalent to being dense; it's stronger. So use arguments without sequences for general spaces, except when it is about sequential convergence notions, like sequential compactness, e.g.

Answer (score -1):

I think your question is same with this question " A set D in a space X is dense in X iff every non-empty open set in X meets D", right?